# I need to stack multiple randomly colored rectangles in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to have hella stacked rectangles that go to the center of the canvas and have them all randomly colored, but my code is wrong and isn't working.

Here is the code i have:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cornerpad = 0;
var rectwidth = 790;
var rectheight = 590;

function drawrectangles() {
    ctx.beginPath;
    ctx.rect(cornerpad, cornerpad, rectwidth, rectheight);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)'
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath;
}   

while(rectheight > 5) {
    rectheight =- 10;
    rectwidth =- 10;
    cornerpad++;
    drawrectangles();
}
```

I am pretty sure I made the while loop wrong since the random color works and the drawing rectangles works. Please help and explain what I did wrong

Comment: That's just a typo `ctx.beginPath` this is a method, you need to call it ( add `()` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some mistakes in your code. First of all, you have `rectheight =- 10;` instead of `rectheight -= 10`. Your line of code is actually equivalent to `rectheight = -10`, so you are just setting both of the variables to -10, not decrementing them by 10.

Then, you used `fill` instead of `fillRect`. There is a fine difference between them, you may read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559603/html5-canvas-fillrect-vs-rect) or [here](https://www.rgraph.net/blog/the-difference-between-rect-strokerect-and-fillrect.html). `fillRect` is a "stand-alone" command that draws and fills a rectangle. So if you issue multiple `fillRect` commands with multiple `fillStyle` commands, each new rect will be filled with the preceeding fillstyle.

For a nicer effect, I recommend using `strokeRect` instead of `rect`, but that's your decision. Also, you may want to play with the condition from the while, to actually make them appear centered.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var cornerpad = 0;
var rectwidth = 790;
var rectheight = 590;

function drawrectangles() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(cornerpad, cornerpad, rectwidth, rectheight);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)';
  
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

while (rectheight > 5) {
  rectheight -= 10;
  rectwidth -= 10;
  cornerpad += 10;
  
  //console.log(`(h, w)=(${rectheight}, ${rectwidth})`);
  drawrectangles();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="790" height="590">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

**Edit:**
I added a version that draws them much nicer, check it out :)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var cornerpad = 0;
var rectwidth = 600;
var rectheight = 400;
var middleLine = rectheight / 2;

function drawrectangles() {
  ctx.strokeRect(cornerpad, cornerpad, rectwidth, rectheight);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)'
  ctx.fillRect(cornerpad, cornerpad, rectwidth, rectheight);
}

while (cornerpad < middleLine) {
  rectheight -= 20;
  rectwidth -= 20;
  cornerpad += 10;

  //console.log(`(h, w)=(${rectheight}, ${rectwidth})`);
  drawrectangles();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Cheers!

**Edit 2:**
Because I was too absorbed by the `=- 10` thing, I forgot to point out to actually use `beginPath` and `closePath` as functions and to call them as `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.closePath()`. Thanks to *Kaiido* for pointing that out and for the two working additional jsfiddles.

Comment: @ShutUp Great! I edited my psot with a much nicer version, maybe you'd like that too :) Just play along with the numbers to make your desired effect. Cheers!

Comment: fill was just fine, the problem was that they didn't call beginPath

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for poiting that out. I added an edit to my post.

Comment: No, you didn't get it. beginPath works with fill(): https://jsfiddle.net/dyzm3wbu/ fillRect has its own [beginPath()rect()] and if you wish to stroke, you just have to call stroke https://jsfiddle.net/dyzm3wbu/2/

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is laying in this expressions `=-` what you mean is `-=`. what you are doing now is setting `rectheight` value to -10 instead of reducing it by 10, thus your while loop just gets executed once.

Comment: thx for reply, i tried that and it did make the one rectangle that appears on screen bigger, but its still only one rectangle and i want hella

Answer (score 1):

You missed some closing brackets and had the =- around the wrong way. I also change the rect to fill straight away.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cornerpad = 0;
var rectwidth = 790;
var rectheight = 590;

function drawrectangles() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)'
    ctx.fillRect(cornerpad, cornerpad, rectwidth, rectheight);
    
}   

while(rectheight > 5) {
  
    rectheight -= 10;
    rectwidth -= 10;
    cornerpad++;
    drawrectangles();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id='canvas' height=590 width=790></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also thank u i just saw the other guys post first but u helped too